# VI editor "ESC" key and "Ctrl + [" do not work correctly

Tags: shell, vim, command-line, command, vi

I am a complete beginner with VI editor.

I had a chance of using the VI editor by typing `git commit` instead of `git commit -m "my comment"` when commenting my commit to my git repository.

I learned that I would go into "edit" mode by pressing `i` in the VI command line. And I also learned that I go back to the command mode by pressing either `ESC` key or `Ctrl + [` key combination. However, neither keys get me out of the "edit" mode.

What happens is that pressing either keys do the same thing, something that seems like accumulating ESC key. Each time I press either key, I see something like below in the bottom line of the screen:

- Pressed once:

`ESC-`

- Pressed twice:

`ESC ESC-`

- Pressed three times:

`ESC ESC ESC`

Since I know that the command to save and exit is `:wq`, when I press `ESC` one time and followed by `:`, the command line immediately turns into to `Eval:`. It seems like `ESC + :` is the key combination for such command.

This seems weird. What would be the problem and how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: my screen]

---

Edit

I found the below codes from `.gitconfig` file in my root directory. Is this causing the problem?

```
[core]
        autocrlf = input
        safecrlf = true
        editor = emacs
```

SOLVED! My problem was due to the `[core] editor` part of the global settings of `.gitconfig`. Once I changed it to `editor = vi` I was able to exit out using VI's shortcuts. Thanks everybody for helping me out.

Comment: If you hit escape once and then wait a second or two does it exit insert mode?

Comment: @EtanReisner If I hit escape once then I kind of exit the insert mode, but I don't get to type what I want. Instead, it combines ESC + something I type. For example, if I press a key pad button, it shows: `<kp-3> is undefined`

Comment: How long did you wait before typing? With some settings and on some terminals vim has to wait to make sure you aren't hitting some key sequence that starts with escape. Wait long enough and it times out the checking and handles escape itself.

Comment: @EtanReisner It seems like it never gets to that state where I can actually type in the command line. For example, when I press ESC key once, the command line stays showing `ESC-` indefinitely. I waited for more than few minutes.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's going on exactly but you can try using `ctrl-o` to temporarily jump out of insert mode (long enough for one command). So `ctrl-o` `:wq` would work.

Comment: If you use `vi`/`vim` manually (instead of from `git`) does it work normally?

Comment: Does `ctrl-c` exit insert mode for you?

Comment: @EtanReisner I just opened a new terminal and tried vi, and it works well.

Comment: @Zach No.. when I did `ctrl-c` it shows me `C-c-` on the command line.

Comment: Do you have `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` set in your environment? Does running `vi -y`/`vim -y` start a vi/vim that works like the one started from `git`? (If so that's `evim` which is close to `evil` and a generally unliked idea.)

Comment: [core]
        editor = emacs

Comment: I found the above from `.gifconfig` file in my root directory. I remember following someone's settings in a tutorial. Is this a problem?

Comment: Why did you decide it is vim in the screenshot? The status line looks like it's emacs.

Comment: @AndyRk It was my mistake. I followed one of a git tutorial and there was a section where it set "alias" in the .gitconfig file along with that `editor = emacs`. Only after reading @EtanReisner's comment, I could think of the possibility that I have changed my settings incautiously.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is something in your ~/.vimrc file that is causing problems.  You might try moving your .vimrc file to a temporary one, then start vim basically without a configuration and see if the problem persists.  If it does then put the file back and start commenting things out until you find it.

It is also possible that your terminal is passing through weird keystrokes or something.

Comment: Hello. `[core] editor = emacs`
     
I found the above from .gifconfig file in my root directory. I remember following someone's settings in a tutorial. Is this a problem?

Comment: It could be if you are wanting to use vim, change emacs to vim and see if that helps.

Comment: It was the problem with my settings in the global `.gitconfig` Thanks for your input!